# How to use all unused swap partition?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, swap

I am sorry if my question is repost from another, but this is quite confusing to me. First, I will start with my situation.

I have a Laptop with 8GB RAM and 320gB HDD. I install Ubuntu 14.04 x64 to my laptop with this configuration from `fdisk -l` result:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd0080a4c

       Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sdb1   *        2048   187011071    93504512   83  Linux
    /dev/sdb2       187011072   203788287     8388608   82  Linux swap / Solaris
    /dev/sdb3       203788288   625139711   210675712    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

As you can see, I have 8gB partition size for `swap`, but when I check my swap used by system, it only detected as 2gB. Here is my `free -m` result:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7686       4756       2929        511        175       2085
-/+ buffers/cache:       2495       5190
Swap:         2047          0       2047
```

When I run `gparted` to see my partition layout, there is exclamation icon on my swap partition and gives me this warning:

```
6.00 GiB of unallocated space within the partition.
```

I did read `SwapFaq`, tried several advice from them but could not solve my problem. I don't want to use/create file that act as swap nor re-create my swap partition. I tried to `swapoff` `swapon` solve the problem.

The question is, how can I use unallocated 6gB of my swap partition so that system read my full swap partition size?

Thank you.

Comment: You could try deleting the partition then recreating it, choosing `swap` as the partition type.

Comment: thank you @Zacharee1, but I don't want to take risk to delete and re-create swap partition. to frustating for me, sorry.

Comment: The answer is literally what I said to do, with the disabling part added.

Comment: you are right, Zacharee1. sorry for confusing, i will edit my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use `swapoff` and `swapon` to fix the problem, because you need to reformat the swap to the full size of the partition, and you cannot do this while it is in use.

First type:

```
sudo swaplabel /dev/sdb2
```

You should see something like:

```
UUID:  ad49d796-e9d9-4bde-8d28-a920c3727d48
```

If that is so, then type the following **very carefully**, where `<UUID>` should be replaced with the value after the `UUID:` you personally got when you ran the previous command.

```
sudo swapoff /dev/sdb2
sudo mkswap -U <UUID> /dev/sdb2
sudo swapon  /dev/sdb2
```

Comment: wow man, thank you verymuch! indeed this solve the problem. One more question, is this setting permanent? I mean, after reboot my laptop, does my swap will be read as 8gB or back to 2gB?

once again, thank you!

Comment: Yes, it's permanent.